# MongoDB / Mongod on ubuntu vps 'Connection refused' error after creating ssh key

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, ubuntu-19.04

I created an ssh key for my vps today. When I then restarted the vps and tried running 'mongo' or 'mongod' im getting these errors:

For mongo:

```
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2019-12-08T18:14:02.345+0100 E  QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, 
connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: 
Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:341:17
@(connect):2:6
2019-12-08T18:14:02.347+0100 F  -        [main] exception: connect failed
2019-12-08T18:14:02.347+0100 E  -        [main] exiting with code 1
```

For Mongod:

```
2019-12-08T18:09:50.619+0100 I  CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 
1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2019-12-08T18:09:50.623+0100 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1169 port=27017 
dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=1cc0f81c.cus9089.kvm.st-srv.eu
2019-12-08T18:09:50.623+0100 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.2.1
2019-12-08T18:09:50.623+0100 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 
edf6d45851c0b9ee15548f0f847df141764a317e
2019-12-08T18:09:50.623+0100 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1b  26 Feb 2019
2019-12-08T18:09:50.623+0100 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2019-12-08T18:09:50.623+0100 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2019-12-08T18:09:50.623+0100 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2019-12-08T18:09:50.623+0100 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1804
2019-12-08T18:09:50.623+0100 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2019-12-08T18:09:50.623+0100 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2019-12-08T18:09:50.623+0100 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2019-12-08T18:09:50.623+0100 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: NonExistentPath: 
Data directory /data/db not found., terminating
2019-12-08T18:09:50.623+0100 I  NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2019-12-08T18:09:50.623+0100 I  NETWORK  [initandlisten] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb- 
27017.sock
2019-12-08T18:09:50.623+0100 I  -        [initandlisten] Stopping further Flow Control ticket 
acquisitions.
2019-12-08T18:09:50.624+0100 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2019-12-08T18:09:50.624+0100 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
```

System-info: Ubuntu 19.04

What can I do to fix this and make it work again without losing my data?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by going over the installation steps again: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

This somehow solved it and now its working